# Combine SimpleCV with TKinter GUI

Tags: tkinter, simplecv

Does anybody know an example combining SimpleCV with TKinter such as placing some widget on the Display? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I answered this on our help forum at:
http://help.simplecv.org

But to relay the message I put up an example here:
https://github.com/ingenuitas/SimpleCV/blob/develop/SimpleCV/examples/display/tkinter-example.py

Here is the code:

```
import SimpleCV
import ImageTk #This has to be installed from the system repos
import Tkinter
import time

Tkinter.Tk()

image = SimpleCV.Image('http://i.imgur.com/FTKqh.jpg') #load the simplecv logo from the web
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.getPIL())
label = Tkinter.Label(image=photo)
label.image = photo # keep a reference!
label.pack() #show the image
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: I think this answer would be better if you put the example in the answer, rather than (or in addition to) a link to the example. Links have a tendency to rot over time. What happens if, for example, you reorganize the location of the examples on github, or move from github to betterhub?

Comment: There is also the flip side to that.  What if the example is updated, or done in a better fashion? What if stackoverflow goes out of business or starts charging for answers?  The best would probably be both methods I suppose.