# Can't use SimpleCV with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, simplecv

I'm writing a program that's going to, among other things, display an image from a USB webcam using Tkinter and SimpleCV to do this. To get started, I tried running the example at [Combine SimpleCV with TKinter GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685984/combine-simplecv-with-tkinter-gui) but no image was displayed. The code is

```
import SimpleCV
import ImageTk #This has to be installed from the system repos
import Tkinter
import time

Tkinter.Tk()

image = SimpleCV.Image('http://i.imgur.com/FTKqh.jpg') #load the simplecv logo from the web
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.getPIL())
label = Tkinter.Label(image=photo)
label.image = photo # keep a reference!
label.pack() #show the image
time.sleep(5)
```

When I ran this, my Raspberry Pi (specifically a BrickPi) did something for five seconds, but nothing visible happened. What could be going on? How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Please include a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as part of your question. Specifically, please post your code directly to SO.

Comment: Welcome to the misery that is SimpleCV.